# I want to Add more Rental guest option in search page like adults and children in Travel Booking WordPress Theme By shinetheme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to Add more Rental guest option in search page like adults and children in Travel Booking WordPress Theme By shinetheme.  is that any way? I want to add Pets Option Over there.
There is not any option in admin.
I want it to work Like Adults and children in front end and admin side also.

I just Try To add Code In Page Template but It only show the option in Front end Not Functionality...